# Dedekind Summation Sawtooth Function Definition

Tags: number-theory

I want to start on Dedekind sums tonight and so my first questions is why is the fractional part defined as $(0)$ rather than what we would commonly define it as, shown below as $(1)$.

The difference is obvious, so it should go without saying I am looking for deeper understanding in an algebraic sense.

$$((x))=\cases{x- \lfloor x \rfloor -1/2&$x \in \mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Z$\cr 0&$x \in  \mathbb Z$\cr} \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad (0)$$

$$((x))=\cases{x- \lfloor x \rfloor &$x \in \mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Z$\cr 0&$x \in  \mathbb Z$\cr} \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\ (1)$$

the first definition was found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_sum)

Comment: a reference on where you found the first definition?

Comment: oh right sorry my mistake I forgot to do that thanks it's up now

Comment: well, as written in your wiki link, (0) is the definition of Sawtooth Function, not of the fractional part

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawtooth_wave  so what does it refer $t-\lfloor t \rfloor$ to being here?

Comment: There are a lot of Sawtooth waves.  (0)  and (1) are two kinds (that differ only by a translation over the $y$ axis). Dedekind uses (0) to develop its theory

Comment: OK so there you go, that is precisely my question, why did he make this choice and what is it's significance?

Comment: The significance is later in the proof.  For example, (0) is better because (0) has mean zero, but (1) has mean $1/2$; and (1) is better because (1) is nonnegative, but (0) isn't.  So which to choose depends on how it will be used in the proof.